Problem with retrieving the checkbox value in WPGetAPI - WordPress
Thank you for your help in advance,
To put it briefly, I have installed the WPGetAPI plugin on WordPress to obtain data from a basic contact form and then transmit it using a post API.
Everything is working perfectly except for one field, which is a checkbox field. It is always empty. I'm sure the value that I've set in the checkbox field is not correct.
this the value i've puted in the setup configuration :

and this is what i find in the logs :

Despite trying many values, I am still unable to solve the issue.

Problem solved by adding the token : (action:posted_data:prog-info:0) as a value in this field
